# How do I use dot notation to map into a value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
await t.set(itemDoc, {
    ['${order.catalogType}.item']: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(item)
}, {merge: true})
```

this doesn't work. I am trying to have the variable `order.CatalogType.item`, the `order.catalogtype` is the variable and the item is the array name. item should be a string. when updating, firestore does the entire `${order.catalogType}`.item. if I remove the `${}` and just use `order.catalogType.item`, I get `Chicken.item` instead of mapping into the chicken and updating the item, it just creates a whole new object called `Chicken.item` ... is there a way to map a string and var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JavaScript, you need to use *backtick quotes* if you want a variable to be interpolated into a string.

```
await t.set(itemDoc, {
    [`${order.catalogType}.item`]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(item)
}, {merge: true})
```

Comment: still the same error, it just adds Chicken.item as a new map object instead of updating

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the document contents more clearly, especially what the document **should** look like after the update, versus what it **actually** looks like?

Comment: it looks like I am unable to edit the quantity of a specific array index containing maps. I'm gonna have to restructure my menu again.